# Problema Ao imprimir uma consulta SQL na Pagina PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho uma consulta SQl e meu código esta imprimido somente a primeira linha da consulta, Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser o meu problema ?

> ERRO: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource,

```
<?php 
    include ("conexao.php");
    //$query = "SELECT SUM(valor), pagador from conta GROUP by pagador"
    $consulta = "SELECT SUM(valor) as soma, pagador from conta GROUP by pagador";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexao,$consulta) or die(mysql_error());
    $linha = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    // se o número de resultados for maior que zero, mostra os dados
    if($total > 0) {
        //inicia o loop que vai mostrar todos os dados
        do {
?>
<p><?=$linha['soma']?> / <?=$linha['pagador'];?></p>
<?php
        // finaliza o loop que vai mostrar os dados
        }while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
        // fim do if 
     }
    mysql_close($conexao);
?>
```

Comment: `or die(mysql_error())` não funciona com o MySQLi, logo é `or die(mysqli_error($conexao));` o mesmo para `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se isso ajuda caro amigo:

```
<?php 
    include ("conexao.php");
    $consulta = "SELECT SUM(valor) as soma, pagador from conta GROUP by pagador";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexao,$consulta) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));

    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "{$linha['soma']} / {$linha['pagador']}</p>";
    }

    mysqli_close($conexao);
?>
```

Não sei o que está no arquivo conexao.php, logo não posso orientar quanto ao mesmo, porém, acredito que o código lá deva ser algo próximo a:

```
<?php $conexao=mysqli_connect("servidor","usuario","senha","banco"); ?>
```